# NSLayoutConstraint crash on iOS 5.1, even with AutoLayout off

Tags: iphone, interface-builder

I have followed this nice [tutorial](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.fr/2010/05/custom-alert-views.html) to create a custom alert view which supports text input.

I designed the alert view NIB with Interface Builder. At runtime on an iOS 5.1 simulator, the error `Could not instantiate class named NSLayoutConstraint` occurred.

The solution to this problem was quickly found on SO: I had to deactivate `AutoLayout` for my XIB/NIB.

That's what I did. However, the same error still occurs.
I double checked, AutoLayout is unchecked for both my Storyboard and my XIB (custom alert view).

I think maybe some reference to `NSLayoutConstraint` has survived somewhere in the project, but `grep -i constraint **/**` gave me no result.

**Any idea other than redesigning my NIB from scratch, with AutoLayout OFF from the start ? (last resort)**

Comment: Extra info: 1) I have tried a clean build with no success. 2) The app runs fine on iOS 6.1

Answer (score 0):

I ended up redesigning the view, with AutoLayout deactivated from the start.

It solved the problem. Looks like I had been suffering from an bug in XCode.